# Populate Dropdown with list<String> using juery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a drop-down, with below code. From back-end service on click of submit button, I get `list<string>` of `camIdListIds`. Now according to `camIdListIds` I need to pre-populate options selected in multiple Drop-down. My drop-down options are Hard-coded, it's options will not dynamically change.

In jsp file-

Drop-down Html:

```
<select name="camIdList" id="camIdList" class="required" multiple="multiple">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="6">camp 1</option>
    <option value="C6">camp 2</option>
    <option value="C7">camp 3</option>
    <option value="CA8">camp 4</option>
    <option value="CA9">camp 5</option>
</select>
```

Jquery-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document ).ready(function() {
   var camIdListIds = "${campaignModel.camIdListIds}";
});
</script>
```

Here, `camIdListIds`  is  `[6, C6, CA8]`

How could I bind options with value from back-ends to drop-down.

jsfiddle:- https://jsfiddle.net/bbjk/xpkgwse4/

Comment: so you want to append these values as new options in your drop-down?

Comment: @Alive to Die  yes, i want to append to dropdown

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **append new data to your dropdown using jQuery** you can use this:

```
camIdListIds = ['CA10', 'CA11', 'CA12']

current_ops = $("#camIdList option").length;
$.each(camIdListIds, function(ind, val) {
    new_op = current_ops + ind;
    $("#camIdList").append($("<option/>").val(val).text('camp ' + new_op));
    })
```

This first checks how many "camps" you have hardcoded, then adds to those dynamically.

[image]